# How can iterate through multiple forms to grab every value entered?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The current code I am using iterates through every form, but I am having issues getting the values that have input type "checkbox". I also do not want grab empty values.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
var params = "";

for (var i=0; i<document.carrierDetails.elements.length; i++){

         var fieldName = document.carrierDetails.elements[i].id;
         var fieldValue = document.carrierDetails.elements[i].value;

         //skips emtpy values      
         if(fieldValue == ""){
               continue;
         }
         else{
               params += "&" + fieldName + "=" + fieldValue;
         }
}
```

Here is my form HTML code:

```
 <form name = safety>
      <div class="divTableRow">
         <div class="divTableCell">Forwarder MC #:</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">
              <input type="text" id="forwarderMC" value="${forwarderMC}">
            </div>
            <div class="divTableCell">DUNS Number:</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">
            <input type="text" id="dunsNumber" value="${dunsNumber}">
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">URL:</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">
            <input type="text" id="companyURL" value="${companyURL}">
            </div>
            <div class="divTableCell">On Time Goal %:</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">
            <input type="text" id="onTimePct" value="${onTimePct}">
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableCell">Oversize Factor:</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">
            <input type="text" id="oversizeFactor" value="${oversizeFactor}">
            </div>
             <div class="divTableCell">Container Yard:</div>
            <div class="divTableCell">
            <input type="checkbox" id="containerYard" value="${containerYard}" style="float: left; width:auto;">
            </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If it is a checkbox use `.checked()` not `.value()`...`.checked()` will return `true` or `false`.

Comment: The solution to this problem is, probably, not to capture all the entered data from multiple form elements but, instead, to use only one form element with all the data that you need to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or with Javascript you do something like this and store them in array.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form[name=safety]');

const inputEls = [...form.querySelectorAll('input[type=text],input[type=checkbox]:checked')]
const data = inputEls.map(input => input.value)
console.log(data)

// OR

const inputEls2 = form.querySelectorAll('input[type=text],input[type=checkbox]:checked');
const data2 = [];
inputEls2.forEach(input => data2.push(input.value));


console.log(data2)
```

```html
<form name="safety">
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell">Forwarder MC #:</div>
    <div class="divTableCell">
      <input type="text" id="forwarderMC" value="${forwarderMC}">
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell">DUNS Number:</div>
    <div class="divTableCell">
      <input type="text" id="dunsNumber" value="${dunsNumber}">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell">URL:</div>
    <div class="divTableCell">
      <input type="text" id="companyURL" value="${companyURL}">
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell">On Time Goal %:</div>
    <div class="divTableCell">
      <input type="text" id="onTimePct" value="${onTimePct}">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell">Oversize Factor:</div>
    <div class="divTableCell">
      <input type="text" id="oversizeFactor" value="${oversizeFactor}">
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell">Container Yard:</div>
    <div class="divTableCell">
      <input type="checkbox" id="containerYard" style="float: left; width:auto;">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It is working properly except when a checkbox is checked it just shows an empty string. I am searching the documentation querySelectorAll, but I cannot seem to find a way to make the checked box show true.

Comment: @Alec what browser are you testing with? Chrome and FF should give value "on"

Comment: I am using Chrome so there must be something wrong with my code.

Comment: @alec can you make a jsfiddle? And i'll take a look

Comment: @alec you mean if you check it, then it's another thing. If the checkbox has checked value by default (as <input type="checkbox" checked />), then it will be added to the array.

Answer (score 1):

If using [JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) then: `var params = $('form[name="safety"]').serialize()`

and also, please rewrite the form tag as `<form name="safety">`
because as far as I remember the whitespace around the equals sign near the attributes does matter - the DOM parser (libxml or smth. similar) understands it as a new attribute.

Comment: I cannot seem to get this working, it keeps coming back empty. I tried using .find('input, textarea, select') to the end of it. I tried using the div tag id around the form, but everything came back with the same result, empty.

Comment: `.serialize()` and `.serializeArray()` work only on forms.